# Access Textbox from JQuery

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, jquery

I'm new to .Net and JQuery and are trying to access a textbox through jquery but can't get it to work, can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET breaks your client ids - Microsoft not complient!  Have you access ClientID store?

```
var textboxclientid = '<%=textbox.ClientID%>';
$('#' + textboxclientid).val('horray');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#your_textboxID");
```

Check [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id#id) link

> Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.
>
> **jQuery( "#id" )**
>
> id: An ID to search for, specified via the id attribute of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Give your Textbox a unique css class then use `$('.classname').val(). This way you don't need to  do inline coding like '<%=textbox.ClientID%>'.

IMHO a cleaner solution....

Comment: by a unique css class i meant a css class only used by this control, i.e. a marker class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#TextBox1").val("Result");
```