# Update a div without reload the page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to update a table in a div with a object data that is stored when the Page_Load load, and I want to update this table without reload the page to avoid unecessary server side loads.

```
public partial class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        User user = new User();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            user = getUser(); //return a user object
        }
}
```

Then in my div "side" I have a

And in other div "buttons" I have two , one to load the user.Name and other to load the user.FullName, both button execute their OnClick methods from MainPage.aspx.cs that add a row in this table with their respective data(Name and FullName)

I want to execute these buttons methods to add a row in this table without reload the page since it's already stored in the 'user' object, so I just need to get the properties the add to the table, not really necessary reach the server to return me this information to update it.

I tried use an UpdatePanel but it just accept buttons that are inside it and it calls the Page_Load and I dont want to do that, also I tried some javascripts/ajax things without sucess.

I hope you understand my needs and help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have all the data you need on page load, then you just need to manipulate the data with javascript. Post-back or ajax would only be required if you need to retrieve new data. Please include your javascript attempts.

Answer (score 0):

How to add rows to tables via jquery: [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

How to call your fields: [Access Textbox from JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047493/access-textbox-from-jquery)